# How to make sure a small string made of alphabet chars have no collision

Tags: algorithm

For example:

Suppose I can have a string of length 4, made of 26 Alphabet chars.

So there can be total 26^4 (around 456976) different permutations.

How can I map these strings to a unique integer in range of 0 to 456976.

like :
aaaa -> 0
aaab -> 1
...
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Base-26 might be your friend.

If you want 1:1 mapping that you described, it is rather simple:

- Map **a** to 0, **b** to 1 ... **z** to 25
- look at your string as a base-26 numeral system: 
  `aaaa == 0000`, which is 0 in decimal 
  `zzzz = 25 * 26 ^ 3 + 25 * 26 ^ 2 + 25 * 26 + 25` which is 456 975 in decimal,

Which shows that we covered the whole range of the unique permutation - in alphabetical order to boot.

Comment: Yes .
Normally below function can map char to int.
`code`
int getChartoInt(char c)
{
 return c -'a';
}

but what if I make sting using only 5 length string using 4 char a,b,c,m so I need to map string between 0 to 4^5 (1024)
and we need to map m to 3.,
Any better approach in that case except mapping it like  below.
`code`
int getChartoInt(char c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case 'a':
            return 0;
        case 'b':
            return 1;
        case 'c':
            return 2;
        case 'm':
            return 3;
    }
}
`code`

Comment: Your formulation is a bit confusing. I get the `c - a` approach to get the value. It is a trick that is quite common in some languages. How does it have to do anything with the string of length 5 please? It went a bit off rails for me, could you please rephrase to a more understandable form?

Comment: Also your question was about a-z strings. Why are we suddenly talking about a,b,c,m? I suppose base-4 could be a solution there, however it is rather unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes I want to get some general logic..
Some day we can encounter a situation where only 4 chars are allowed to form a sting of length n. like any 4..So get it under the range we need to map first char to 0 , second to 1, third char to 2 and forth char to 3

Comment: That is most likely worth a separate Q&A as it is beyond the scope of this question and too lengthy for a comment.

Comment: @Sanjeev: for your more general problem, one easy approach is to store the set of legal characters in a `std::string legal`, then covert any given character `c` to a value for use in your "base-_N_" calculation by calling [legal.find(c)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).  Scanning short contiguous memory blocks is efficient enough for most purposes.